# Google Dataprep Sort By Column

Tags: excel, google-cloud-dataprep

I've tried searching for this and had no luck so sorry if it is a duplicate.
I am looking to see if I can sort an Excel sheet by column, in a custom order, using Google Dataprep. I am looking to use the file in BQ afterwards which I why I wish to use Dataprep.

The column name is Stage, and the values are: Closed - Won, Stage Three, Stage Two, Stage One, Prospect, Closed - Lost. Not appearing in that order, but that's the order I want to sort them in.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why you think you need this sort happened in Excel vs just load csv into BQ and then do whatever logic is needed including sorting?

Comment: Probably you could map those to numeric values in a new column using [CASE](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/CASE-Function_90112182). Then, use it as column reference in [Order by](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Transform-Builder_57344873#step-3---grouping-ordering-and-naming).

Comment: It needs to be stored seperately outside of BQ and I'd rather not rely on BQ to do it incase our usage changes. I'm looking to do it in dataprep so it isn't in excel. I should have said xlsx/csv instead of Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working even if my solution is a little bit convoluted and consisting of the three following recipe steps (click on `Add Step` from the `Edit Recipe` menu for each one):

1) Type `derive` in the text box and press enter. In the `Formula` section input the following:

```
case([stage == 'Closed - Won',0,stage == 'Stage Three',1,stage == 'Stage Two',2,stage == 'Stage One',3,stage == 'Prospect',4,stage == 'Closed - Lost',5])
```

This will map each of the possible stage to a numerical value so we can use a custom sort in step 2. Define the new column name, for example, `orderingPattern`. Remember to change `stage` for the actual column name if those differ.

[image]
2) Confirm the step and add a new one. Type `window` this time and use a dummy formula (I used `window = id`) and in Order by select the previous column (i.e. `orderingPattern`). Now the preview should already be ordered as desired:

[image]
3) Drop the extra columns as we don't need them anymore (`orderingPattern` and `window`)

[image]

Final result shows now all the rows sorted according to the custom `stage` order in step 1:

[image]